# where is the right place for composer bin-dir?

Tags: php, composer-php

Inside composer.json we have chance to set bin-dir as in below example.

```
"config": {
  "bin-dir": "bin/"
}
```

Does anyone knows if there is any pros and cons of placing "bin" directory inside vendor folder or outside(just one level up, within project root) of it?

Comment: Keep it outside vendor. It has no place there. It's not package. Some packages CAN have `/bin` but that's another story all together. Keep it in top level directory, where `/vendor` would be stored too.

Comment: @Andrew you are absolutely right and I agree. I prefer to keep it outside of vendor since it is not a package. And this is only making our directory structure more clean! However what I am trying to understand if we get any other benefit by doing so or worse.. if we create some disadvantages?

Comment: It doesn't create any disadvantages that I can think of.

Comment: remember that this is the place where registered binaries from installed packages will be installed to this dir, so you need to keep that in mind when you add your own scripts there (they might be overwritten) https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/vendor-binaries.md#can-vendor-binaries-be-installed-somewhere-other-than-vendor-bin-

Comment: well it must be as long as you have the same naming, right..